# Is there a more idiomatic way of replacing a pointer?

Tags: c++, memory

Consider the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdexcept>

class Foo {
    public:
        Foo(int n) { val =n; printf("Hi %d\n", val); };
        ~Foo() { printf("Bye %d\n", val); };
    private:
        int val;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> p = nullptr;  // I don't know what I want yet
    p = std::make_shared<Foo>(1); // OK, I've decided

    // I've changed my mind, it needs to be something else
    p = nullptr;
    p = std::make_shared<Foo>(2);

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is:

```
Hi 1
Bye 1
Hi 2
Bye 2
```

It's a contrived example. Foo is a fairly uninteresting. It just prints out info regarding its lifetime.

The logic behind the code is: I declare p, but I don't know what it should be initially. I then decide that I know what it is: it should take the value 1. In my real code, this value might last a long time.

Some time later, I decide that it shouldn't be 1, it should be 2. So whatever it was before should be destroyed, and be replaced by something else.

So far, my understanding is that the code above is good in terms of memory  management and is robust under exceptions.

Is there a more idiomatic way of saying:

```
p = nullptr;
p = std::make_shared<Foo>(2);
```

I can't just write the last line, because I want to say that what I had before needs to be destroyed.

Comment: _"I can't just write the last line, because I want to say that what I had before needs to be destroyed."_ What makes you think only the second line won't trigger destruction of the former value other than assigning `nullptr`?

Comment: Because when I comment out "p= nullptr" I get the output Hi 1, Hi 2, Bye 1, Bye 2. IOW, the first assignment lasts too long.

Comment: This is because the **2** object is created before the assignment to `p`. If you really need the **1** object to be destroyed before **2** is created you need to set `p` to `nullptr` before creating **2**. There's no idiom for this since it's such an obscure requirement.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<Foo> p = nullptr; // I don't know what I want yet` => It's a fundamental enough feature that smart pointers have default construction to being empty that I would not put the nullptr here "for emphasis".  YMMV.

Comment: Sounds like a use case for boost::optional or std::optional (C++17)

Answer (score 2):

Just assigning to the pointer is enough to inform you don't need the previous value. You don't get to say whether it should be destroyed since it's a *shared* pointer and may have other owners.

In my opinion just assigning is enough but you may prefer to use [`shared_ptr::reset()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset).

Comment: `reset()` is less efficient since it causes a separation of the control block and the instance of `Foo`.

Comment: @RichardHodges, I agree, except [when it isn't](https://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/make_shared-almost-a-silver-bullet/).

Comment: But let's be realistic. memory locality is almost always more important than whether we hold on to some extra memory for a little while. copying a shared_ptr or locking a weak_ptr is a common operation, and is *almost always* followed by accessing the pointee object itself. In which case, in the make_shared case, the beginning of the object (the hot part) is already in the data cache waiting for you.

Comment: @Motti. Ah, good point. I think what I actually want for the code I have in development is a unique_ptr, rather than a shared_ptr. I'm still wrapping my head around C++!

Answer (score 1):

Since you want idiomatic (good!), let's be idiomatic:

```
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int n)
    : val(n)
    {
        std::cout << "Hi " << val << "\n";
    };
    ~Foo() {
        std::cout << "bye " << val << "\n";
    };
private:
    int val;
};

int main()
{
    auto p = std::shared_ptr<Foo>();  // I don't know what I want yet
    p = std::make_shared<Foo>(1); // OK, I've decided

    // I've changed my mind, it needs to be something else
    p = std::make_shared<Foo>(2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing else you need to do here

```
p = std::make_shared<Foo>(2);
```

This line destroys previous object in p if it was the last reference to this object. Then it assigns new shared_ptr to p with new value